# To what extent can Google access data in the standard Android storage locations without restriction?

Tags: android

Android docs lists a number of places to store data [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

To what extent can Google access data in these places assuming the developer does not want them to have it?

In other words, if I save a private piece of data in an app that I make in my "[private internal storage](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html#StoringData)", and make no use of Google Services (Play, Maps, etc.) whatever, does Google still have access to that data somehow?  Does my carrier?

Does the answer to this change if I'm using Android's own [Keystore](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyStore.html) to encrypt that data?

Note that I'm not talking about a physical or software compromise of the device here, I mean legally.  What do they say, what might be the case (post-Snowden), what probably is the case.

Comment: Here is a decent thread on android privacy, not exactly what you were asking about though http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/43361/what-information-does-stock-android-send-to-google-by-default-and-how-do-i-opt

Answer (score 1):

For legal issues regarding the data, you need to read the android terms of Use. There is probably a section on law enforcement.

as far as where the data is: On my google account one of the sync options is called "AppData".